# CSS repeat animation without using animation-iteration-count

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to write a Simon Says game with JQuery and have hit a snag.

For some reason, if I have a repeat item in my "flash sequence" only one of the instances flashes.

I.e `game.displaySequence( [ 1, 1 ] );` only flashes once, whereas

`game.displaySequence( [ 3, 1, 4, 2 ] );` works fine.

Because of the way I've set things up, `animation-iteration-count` is probably not relevant.

I have researched the problem, and tried various suggestions such as removing the animation class after each animation, but no luck.

Code is below - any help much appreciated.

JS/jQuery:

```
game = {

    // Game constants
    flashSpeed: 0.4,

    // Display sequence to player
    displaySequence: function( seq ) {
        seq.forEach( function( val, pos ) {
            // Flash element based on list contents
            $( "#box" + val ).css( "animation", "blinker " + game.flashSpeed + "s linear " + pos * game.flashSpeed + "s 1" );

        } );
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: When your code loops to the 2nd `1` (#box1) it *replaces* the 'animation' css with the new one (with the later delayed start).  You'll have to rethink how you queue the animations, possible using `setTimeout` instead of `pos*game.flashSpeed` or using jquery (as it's tagged jquery) animation instead.

Comment: Having a quick look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations and it looks like you can supply `blinker` multiple times.  You might need to loop through first to determine what the css should be - or alternatively - loop through the boxes rather than the vals and extract how many times and what positions.  But should be possible to have `blinker` run multiple times with different `animation-delay` values.